# React Native 0.57 + CocoaPods - Failure to locate linked libraries only in CI Environment

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, visual-studio-app-center

I am hitting a brick wall at the moment trying to get my app to build in VS AppCenter. It's a react-native project, with some dependencies brought in via cocoapods.

Everything builds locally fine (clean clone on clean vm)

In the CI Environment in AppCenter though I get the following errors:

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-adroxiklvgljuicvfqowylcdxjrt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/unisafe/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/BVLinearGradient'
ld: library not found for -lGoogle-Maps-iOS-Utils
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Archive Failed`

I get the first warning a number of times for each pod.

Here is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
project './projectname.xcproj'
target 'projectname' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for projectname
  pod 'AppCenter/Push', '~> 1.10.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.10.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.10.0'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared'
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'ART',
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
  ]

  pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path  # Remove this line if you don't want to support Google Maps on iOS
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Remove this line if you don't want to support Google Maps on iOS
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS

  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'
  pod 'react-native-background-timer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-background-timer'
  pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  pod 'lottie-ios', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-ios'
  pod 'lottie-react-native', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-react-native'
  pod 'TouchID', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-touch-id'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  platform :ios, '11.0'
  # target 'projectnameTests' do
  #   inherit! :search_paths
  #   # Pods for testing
  # end

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

In my library search paths i have:

```
$(inherited)
$(BUILD_DIR)/${CONFIGURATION}$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
"${PODS_ROOT}"
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution...but resolved this by removing and re-adding everything under 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' in XCode build settings.

I'll close this, but if anyone else has this issue, reply here or PM - happy to help.